# why does a a nodejs array shift/push loop run 1000x slower above array length 87369?

Tags: node.js, performance, v8

Why is the speed of nodejs array shift/push operations not linear in the size of the array?  There is a dramatic knee at 87370 that completely crushes the system.

Try this, first with 87369 elements in q, then with 87370.  (Or, on a 64-bit system, try 85983 and 85984.)  For me, the former runs in .05 seconds; the latter, in 80 seconds -- 1600 times slower.  (observed on 32-bit debian linux with node v0.10.29)

```
q = [];

// preload the queue with some data
for (i=0; i<87369; i++) q.push({});

// fetch oldest waiting item and push new item
for (i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    q.shift();
    q.push({});
    if (i%10000 === 0) process.stdout.write(".");
}
```

64-bit debian linux v0.10.29 crawls starting at 85984 and runs in .06 / 56 seconds.  Node v0.11.13 has similar breakpoints, but at different array sizes.

Comment: I fixed the typo in 85983 (5, not 6)

Answer (score 3):

Shift is a very slow operation for arrays as you need to move all the elements but V8 is able to use a trick to perform it fast when the array contents fit in a page (1mb).

Empty arrays start with 4 slots and as you keep pushing, it will resize the array using formula `1.5 * (old length + 1) + 16`.

```
var j = 4;
while (j < 87369) {
    j = (j + 1) + Math.floor(j / 2) + 16
    console.log(j);
}
```

Prints:

```
23
51
93
156
251
393
606
926
1406
2126
3206
4826
7256
10901
16368
24569
36870
55322
83000
124517
```

So your array size ends up actually being 124517 items which makes it too large.

You can actually preallocate your array just to the right size and it should be able to fast shift again:

```
var q = new Array(87369); // Fits in a page so fast shift is possible

// preload the queue with some data
for (i=0; i<87369; i++) q[i] = {};
```

If you need larger than that, use [the right data structure](https://github.com/petkaantonov/deque)

Comment: thanks, but the issue is with `shift`, not `unshift` -- the array is getting smaller (it was preallocated to 87369 with the appends).  v8 is using memmove() to move them and that takes only 0.04 ms; the total time taken is 1.10 ms, 25x slower.  The slowdown is from inside RecordWrites.  Why is RecordWrites needed in this case?  What does it do?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, changed it to `q = new Array(20000)`, but it's still slow.

Comment: You cannot pre-allocate with `.push`, it will dynamically resize and when the numbers get large the resize is pretty generous because resize operation is very expensive (need to copy all elements to a new array)

Comment: But I'm not timing push, I'm timing shift.  My point was that by the time shift runs, the array will have been allocated.  Allocation before use is pre-allocation.  When shift runs, the array is already at its maximum size; it will not get any bigger.

Comment: The array size when you start shifting is 124517 because of dynamic resizes, so the array will be too large for new space and fast shift cannot be implemented. I suggested pre allocating exact size because 87000 items fit in new space.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would make the sample code no longer exhibit the symptom.  I'm not trying to speed up the demo, I'm trying to understand whether there is anything in v8 that is unnecessarily slowing down array shifts.  array push is very fast even though it also has to grow the array (10 mill in 500 ms, 100k in 7ms).

Answer (score 1):

I started digging into the v8 sources, but I still don't understand it.

I instrumented deps/v8/src/builtins.cc:MoveElemens (called from Builtin_ArrayShift, which implements the shift with a memmove), and it clearly shows the slowdown:  only 1000 shifts per second because each one takes 1ms:

```
AR: at 1417982255.050970: MoveElements sec = 0.000809
AR: at 1417982255.052314: MoveElements sec = 0.001341
AR: at 1417982255.053542: MoveElements sec = 0.001224
AR: at 1417982255.054360: MoveElements sec = 0.000815
AR: at 1417982255.055684: MoveElements sec = 0.001321
AR: at 1417982255.056501: MoveElements sec = 0.000814
```

of which the memmove is 0.000040 seconds, the bulk is the heap->RecordWrites (deps/v8/src/heap-inl.h):

```
void Heap::RecordWrites(Address address, int start, int len) {
  if (!InNewSpace(address)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      store_buffer_.Mark(address + start + i * kPointerSize);
    }
  }
}
```

which is (store-buffer-inl.h)

```
void StoreBuffer::Mark(Address addr) {
  ASSERT(!heap_->cell_space()->Contains(addr));
  ASSERT(!heap_->code_space()->Contains(addr));
  Address* top = reinterpret_cast<Address*>(heap_->store_buffer_top());
  *top++ = addr;
  heap_->public_set_store_buffer_top(top);
  if ((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(top) & kStoreBufferOverflowBit) != 0) {
    ASSERT(top == limit_);
    Compact();
  } else {
    ASSERT(top < limit_);
  }
}
```

when the code is running slow, there are runs of shift/push ops followed by runs of 5-6 calls to `Compact()` for every MoveElements.  When it's running fast, MoveElements isn't called until a handful of times at the end, and just a single compaction when it finishes.

I'm guessing memory compaction might be thrashing, but it's not falling in place for me yet.

Edit: forget that last edit about output buffering artifacts, I was filtering duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

this bug had been reported to google, who closed it without studying the issue.

https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3059

> When shifting out and calling tasks (functions) from a queue (array)
>   the GC(?) is stalling for an inordinate length of time.
>
> 114467 shifts is OK
>   114468 shifts is problematic, symptoms occur

the response:

> he GC has nothing to do with this, and nothing is stalling either.
>
> Array.shift() is an expensive operation, as it requires all array
>   elements to be moved. For most areas of the heap, V8 has implemented a
>   special trick to hide this cost: it simply bumps the pointer to the
>   beginning of the object by one, effectively cutting off the first
>   element. However, when an array is so large that it must be placed in
>   "large object space", this trick cannot be applied as object starts
>   must be aligned, so on every .shift() operation all elements must
>   actually be moved in memory.
>
> I'm not sure there's a whole lot we can do about this. If you want a
>   "Queue" object in JavaScript with guaranteed O(1) complexity for
>   .enqueue() and .dequeue() operations, you may want to implement your
>   own.

Edit: I just caught the subtle "all elements must be moved" part -- is RecordWrites not GC but an actual element copy then?  The memmove of the array contents is 0.04 milliseconds.  The RecordWrites loop is 96% of the 1.1 ms runtime.

Edit: if "aligned" means the first object must be at first address, that's what memmove does. What is RecordWrites?

Comment: In generational garbage collection that v8 uses, record write is in a sense the hook to check if one is making an object in the old space point to an object in new space.

Comment: ah, that's useful, thanks.  So did the memmove() move pointers in the array, or the objects themselves?  No new objects are being created, nor is the list being gc'd